# complex K3 surfaces with automorphisms of given orders

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Concerning complex K3 surfaces, there are various methods to show the non-existence of an automorphism of certain orders. The usually way is to investigate the action of the automorphism on the space $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$.

Do we in general know how to produce or show the existence of a K3 surface which admits some automorphisms of give order?

As an example, can we have a complex K3 surface which admits an automorphism of order $5$ and another of order $7$ at the same time?

Moreover, do we have a family $M_{(n)}$ of complex K3 surfaces which admits an automorphisms of some order $n>1$?

We can also ask about the intersection behavior of these $M_{(n)}$. It is basically the same as the first question.

Comment: The maximum order is 66. See J. Keum, *Orders of automorphisms of K3 surfaces*, Adv. Math. 303 (2016), 39-87, where all possible orders are determined.

Comment: @abx Oh yes, let me edit my question.